# May i expand or collapse kendo gantt tasks programmatically?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo gantt chart http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/gantt

Can i expand and collapse its items programmatically?

Kendo gantt documentation hasn't such methods, but may be is possible to expand tasks via jQuery?

Also i tried expand tasks by changing `expanded` property for selected task:

```
var selection = gantt.select();
if (selection) {
    var task = gantt.dataItem(selection);
    console.log('task.expanded = ' + task.expanded); // shows true or false depending on visual state
    task.expanded = true;
    console.log('task.expanded = ' + task.expanded); // always shows true
}
```

Property `expanded` sets, but visually nothing has changes

Comment: You are not giving enough detail. For starter, imagine yourself as someone else and read the post again and see if you can understand **clearly**. Please edit you post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this via the datasource and the chart will update without having to manually call refresh.  `$("#gantt").data("kendoGantt").dataSource.view()[0].set("expanded", false)`

[docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/gantttask#fields-expanded)

Comment: If you try to invoke `set` once per each task to expand/collapse them _all_ at once it will be very slow because it will trigger full recalc many times. You can use the direct assignment as in question for each and then invoke `set` for just the first or the last item. This way only one recalc for all items is used. Makes it essentially faster.